# Device NOT COMPATIBLE for Android Studio

Tags: android, device, incompatibility

I've connected a Virgin Mobile Kyocera EVENT mobile phone (which uses the Android operating system) to my computer. I'm developing an app using Android Studio. I have the driver installed for the phone. When I select to RUN the app and the device selection dialog comes up I can indeed see the Kyocera EVENT phone listed. BUT, in the column titled "Compatible" it shows "NO".

Does this mean that the Kyocera EVENT phone cannot run the app? That it doesn't work with Android Studio?

Is there some selection I have to make in the project in order to allow it to be compatible?

Comment: I can see that in the AndroidManifest.xml file for the project there are a couple of lines that seem to specify a "target" for compiling the app, as follows:

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

I tried editing that so it shows '3' as both the min and target Sdk. But when the project actually builds those values get automatically set back to 7 and 19. I read somewhere that something in the build.gradle file overrides the values in the AndroidManifest file.
But I'm still at a loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Build-Customization

Comment: The Kyocera Event does work with Android Studio since I have been using it for Development for a few months.  I have to unplug and plugin in the USB cable for every build to get it to work.